# Rails 3 render partial outside view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on a multisite for a client for a skateboarding website. So far everything is great but I am starting to get stuck on the whole partial thing. I have a site and site has_many :albums(Album also belongs to site) but when I try to render albums from a site on the sites homepage i get **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class**?

I have am trying to render albums/_album.html.erb on the sites/show page to display a site latest's album on the homepage of the site.

**Albums Controller**

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @albums = Album.all
  end

  def show
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @album = Album.new
  end

  def edit
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @album = current_site.albums.build(params[:album])

    if @album.save
     redirect_to albums_path, :notice => 'Album was successfully created.'
    end
  end

  def update
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])

    if @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
     redirect_to album_path(@album), :notice => 'Album was successfully updated.'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    @album.destroy
  end
end
```

**Sites Controller**

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @sites = Site.all
  end

  def show
    @site = Site.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
  end

  def new
    @site = Site.new
  end

  def edit
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @site = Site.new(params[:site])

    if @site.save
     redirect_to @site, :notice => 'Signed up!'
    end
  end

  def update
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])

    if @site.update_attributes(params[:site])
      redirect_to @site, :notice => 'Site was successfully updated.'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])
    @site.destroy
  end
end
```

**Site Show.html**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>First name:</b>
  <%= @site.first_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Last name:</b>
  <%= @site.last_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Subdomain:</b>
  <%= @site.subdomain %>
</p>

<%= render :partial => 'albums/album'%>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_site_path(@site) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', sites_path %>
```

**Albums/_album.html.erb**

```
<%= div_for @album do %>
  <h2><%= @album.title %></h2>
   <%= image_tag @album.photo.url(:small) %>
<% end %>
```

Am I missing something in my albums controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your show.html, you need to pass in the collection of albums to the render method

```
<%= render :partial => 'albums/album', :collection => @site.albums %>
```

Within the _album.html.erb partial, you need to reference the album attribute as a local attribute, like so

```
<%= div_for album do %>
  <h2><%= album.title %></h2>
  ...
```

You can read more about partials here [3.4.5 Rendering Collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Tried the above but still did not work. Everything works fine except when I have `<%= @album.title %>` rails says undefined method `title'

Comment: The instance attribute "@album" is never defined in the SiteController so you can't use it. Try using the local attribute <%= album.title %>